# NoReverseMatch at /collection/6/

Tags: python, django

I'm a beginner at Django/programming in general. I have a problem with a redirecting url button on one of my HTML pages. Basically I have a collection page where one can add plants. The collection page displays all of the added plants and an add plant button for the user to enter another one to the database.

Then when you click on a plant, you see the plant, the picture you added, and the nickname. There is also other data that can be added, for that I made a CreateView that adds details such as date purchased and notes.

Now this page works and when I go to the URL manually I can update a plant. However when I want to add an 'add details' button to my html file of a specific plant, I get this error that I just cannot solve.

Here is some mandatory code:
**Models.py**

```
class PlantDetail(models.Model):
    """This class contains various types of data of added plants"""
    """links the details to one plants"""
    from datetime import date
    plant = models.ForeignKey(Plant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_purchased = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    notes = models.TextField()
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        """Return the detail input from the user"""
        return self.notes
        
        
    def age(self):
        """Return the age of the plant in days"""
        age_days = datetime.date.today() - date_purchased
        return age_days.days

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', args=[int(self.plant_id)])
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

    # Landing page
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    
    # Collection page
    path('collection/', login_required(CollectionListView.as_view()), name='collection'),
    
    # Detail page for a plant
    path('collection/<int:plant_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),

    # New plant creation page
    path('collection/add/', login_required(PlantCreateView.as_view()), name='plant-create'),

    # Add details to an existing plant
    path('collection/<int:plant_id>/add_details/', login_required(PlantDetailCreateView.as_view()), name='plantdetail-create'),
```

**views.py**

```
# Class based views
class CollectionListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'plntz_main/collection.html'
    context_object_name = 'plants'

    def get_queryset(self):

        return Plant.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).order_by('name')

class PlantCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Plant
    fields = ['name', 'nickname', 'image', 'category']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PlantDetailCreateView(CreateView):
    model = PlantDetail
    fields = ['date_purchased', 'notes']


    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.plant_id = self.kwargs['plant_id']
        return super().form_valid(form)



# Defined Views
def home(request):
    """Landing page for PLNTZ"""
    return render(request, 'plntz_main/home.html')


@login_required
def detail(request, plant_id):
    """The page that displays the detail linked the one of the plants"""
    plant_detail = get_object_or_404(Plant, pk=plant_id)
    if plant_detail.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    context = {
        'plant_detail' : plant_detail
    }
    return render(request, 'plntz_main/detail.html', context)
```

**detail.html**

```
{% extends "plntz_main/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1> {{ plant_detail.name }} </h1>
<p><img src={{ plant_detail.image.url }}></p>
<p> Nickname: {{ plant_detail.nickname}}
<p> Category: {{ plant_detail.category }}
{% for detail in plant_detail.plantdetail_set.all %}
    
    <p>Date purchased: {{ detail.date_purchased }} </p>
    <p>Notes: {{ detail.notes }}</p>

{% endfor %}


<form>
    <button formaction="{% url 'plantdetail-create' %}">Add details</button>
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

I get the error when I navigate from a plant in the collection to its detail page. Meaning that the error happens within the detail.html. As soon as I delete the button formaction line of code the page works again.

Extra info from the error I get:

> Error during template rendering In template
> D:\PLNTZ\plntz_main\templates\plntz_main\base.html, error at line 0
>
> Reverse for 'plantdetail-create' with no arguments not found. 1
> pattern(s) tried: ['collection/(?P<plant_id>[0-9]+)/add_details/$']

Hope someone can help me out here!

Answer (score 1):

Your plantdetail-create page requires additional parameter - int:plant_id which needs to be included in the button I presume

```
{% url 'plantdetail-create' plant_id=plant_id %}
```

Comment: Hello @zhivko zaikov thanks for the reply! I'm still getting an error: oReverseMatch at /collection/5/
Reverse for 'plantdetail-create' with keyword arguments '{'plant_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['collection/(?P<plant_id>[0-9]+)/add_details/$']

Comment: I am not sure if this is a valid code:

def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', args=[int(self.plant_id)])

as self.plant_id should refer to PlantDetail where there is no "plant_id". You can test it with pk or other value?

Comment: hi, i tried and it does not change anything. PlantDetail is linked with a PK to Plant class, so the plant_id does link to it.

Answer (score 0):

After trying myself I found the awnser.

My context in detail is plant_detail, so obviously I had to use `{% url 'plantdetail-create' plant_detail.id %}` instead of `{% url 'plantdetail-create' plant.id %`